# Embedding OpenCV Viz3d and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'd like to have an OpenCv Viz3d window in my Qt application.  I'm aware that there are other similar questions, but those are in regards to OpenCV's 2d imaging capabilities.

So far, my approach has been to create a class that inherits from QWidget and cv::viz::Viz3d.  However, I can't figure out how to override cv::viz::Viz3d's paint event to display inside of the GUI rather than its own window.

If there's a way to retrieve a cv::Mat from cv::viz::Viz3d, that could potentially work as well; however, it doesn't seeem like I can get a cv::Mat from Viz3d.

Answer (score 1):

Viz3d implementation depends on the build VTK. Internally, it uses the Qt and OpenGL (depending on the assembly).

Since viz3d uses its own event loop, it is unrealistic to use in one thread with the other windows. Personally, I have created a separate QThread for the window and work with it in another thread (data sends signals through QImage([QImage to cv::Mat](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/))).

You can also access this window by using the static method QApplication::activeWindow(), or your own version. Then you can capture an image (grab()) in this window and submit to his own.